# Linearity of a subset of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, multilinear-algebra

Suppose that $X$ is a vector space and $A$ is a subset of $X$. Let $Y$ be a proper subspace of $X$. Consider the collection

$M=\{a+Y:~a\in A\}.$

It is given that the collection $M$ is linear. In fact,

$M=\{x+Y:~x\in X\}.$

From this can we conclude that $A$ is a subspace of $X$? If not then what structure $A$ should possess? A detailed answer (or Hint or example or counter example) would be of much help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** We may assume that $A$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: If $Y=X$ then there is no condition on $A$. Any set $A$ satisfies these properties.

Comment: Can you say what it means for a set to be linear?

Comment: By linearity, I mean that the set is closed under vector space operation, i.e., it is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication @ancientmathematician.

Comment: Thank you @geetha290krm. I have edited $Y$ to be a proper subspace.

Comment: If $Z$ is a subspace of $X$ then with $A=Z\setminus\{0\}$ we get that $M=Y+Z$ is a subspace so that's a trivial possibility you have to rule out.

Comment: You need to understand the notation $M=\{a+Y:~a\in A\}$.  For each $a$, the notation $a+Y$ is a subset of $X$ [ sometimes called a "coset" of $Y$ ].  So $M$ itself is not a subset of $X$: instead $M$ is a set of subsets of $M$.  In order to show $M$ is a linear space you need to define addition of cosets, and scalar multiples of cosets.

Comment: $M$ is linear with respect to the usual addition and scalar multiplication of cosets and as usual  $M$ is not a subspace of $X.$ It is a quotient space. @GEdgar